# サーバーが送信するJson文字列のデータバイト数を知りたい。

Tags: php, c#, laravel, unity2d

Unityで開発を行っています。

アプリ側で通信進捗をプログレスバーで表示しようとしているのですが、
受信するデータの最大バイト数を知りたいと考えております。

サーバーから取得するデータはJson形式の文字列になります。
それを「UnityWebRequest.downloadedBytes」とデータバイト数でプログレスバーを表示する予定です。

サーバー上のファイルではないので計算しなければならない点もあるとは思いますが、
機能としてバイト数を取得できるものがあれば楽になるかと思います。

Unity側でのバイト数を取得できる機能などありますでしょうか。
またはlalavelで送信データのバイト数を計る機能などありますでしょうか。

よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: まず、サーバ側に送信するデータのバイト数を返す機能があるのか、あるとすればUnityから利用する方法はどうなっているのか、といった事を調べるのが先なのではないでしょうか？サーバに機能が無いのに、それをUnityから利用することは不可能ですからね。
まずは、利用されているサーバの詳細情報を質問に追加するのが良いと思います。

Comment: 些細な違いかもしれませんが、クライアントサイドでの話をするのであれば「サーバが送信する」より「サーバから受け取る」の方がしっくりくる気がします。